# Ruby class inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I defined a node class and player class as following:

```
class Node < OpenStruct
  def initialize(parent,tag,&block)
    super()
    self.parent = parent
    self.parent.children << self unless parent.nil?
    self.children = []
    self.tag = tag
    instance_eval(&block) unless block.nil?
  end
end

class Player < Node
  def initialize(parent)
    Node.new(parent,:player) do 
      self.turn_num = 1
    end
  end
end
```

The instance variable player was created by

```
player = Player.new(room) # room is the parent node which was defined
puts player.turn_num
```

And I got the error:

```
in `method_missing': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Could you help me figure out where went wrong? Thanks!

Edit:

The problem should be the initialize in the Player class. I changed my codes

```
class Player < Node
      def self.new(parent)
        Node.new(parent,:player) do 
          self.turn_num = 1
        end
      end
 end
```

Then there is no error.What's wrong with the initialize here?

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory: you have a `nil` and you are trying to do stuff with it.

Comment: @PicklishDoorknob Sure. I wanted to figure out where generated a nil. I found player is not a nil

Comment: @PicklishDoorknob .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/ostruct.rb:174:in `method_missing': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
 from test.rb:6:in `<main>' (referring to the line 'puts player.turn_num')

Comment: @PicklishDoorknob Edited my question a little bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to initialize a Node inside Player, because any Player instance is already *also* a Node instance. Instead, you should pass the expected arguments into `super`:

```
class Player < Node
  def initialize(parent,&block)
    super(parent, :player, &block)
    self.turn_num = 1
  end
end
```

Generally, it's a bad idea to override `.new` - this is defined by default for all Ruby objects to allocate memory and then run the initialize method (if it exists). When you override it as `self.new`, you're just returning a bare `Node` instance, not a `Player` instance.